# Increment Variables Understanding

Tags: php

Can someone help me understand this? When I output the code in PHP it gives the answers **a is 11** and **b is 10**, but I thought if I were to echo **a** it would equal **10**, where as if I echo **b** it would be **10+1 ($a++)**.

See code

```
$a = 10;
$b = $a++;
  echo $a;
  echo $b;
```

Comment: Returns $a, then increments $a by one. - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: If you want a=10 and b=11, change the 2nd line to $b=$a+1

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius or `$b = ++$a;` which does the increment before the assign

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an idea using cases and interpretations:

**Assuming:**

```
let a = 10;
let b = 0;
```

**Case 1: `b = a++`**

Interprets to:

```
b = a;     // b now is 10
a = a + 1; // a now is 11
```

**Case 2: `b = a--`**

Interprets to:

```
b = a;     // b now is 10
a = a - 1; // a now is 9
```

**Case 3: `b = ++a`**

Interprets to:

```
a = a + 1; // a now is 11
b = a;     // b now is 11
```

**Case 4: `b = --a`**

Interprets to:

```
a = a - 1; // a now is 9
b = a;     // b now is 9
```

**Note**

Expression like `a++` or `--a` changes the original variable. If you don't want to change the original variable, you need to write it like:

```
b = a + 1;
// Now b = 11 and a is still 10
```